# How to create new column in R based on missing values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following data

```
Sample_ID<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")
Score<-c(100, 200, 300, 400, NA, NA)
DF<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Score)
```

How to create a new variable called `Score_status` where all the samples having NA (missing value) will be coded as 0 and those having scores will be coded as 1. I am looking for following output.

```
Sample_ID     Score    Score_status
a1             100      1
a2             200      1
a3             400      1
a4             NA       0
a5             NA       0
```

How to do this in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
DF$Score_status <- ifelse(is.na(DF$Score),0,1)

  Sample_ID Score Score_status
1        a1   100            1
2        a2   200            1
3        a3   300            1
4        a4   400            1
5        a5    NA            0
6        a6    NA            0
```

Comment: Getting this error:  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Score_status, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6

Comment: @Aryh Updated answer, just check the names of `DF`, you can be confused by `score` and `Score`.

Comment: Code golf: `+!is.na(DF$Score)`.

Comment: @r2evans using partial matching `+!is.na(DF$Sc)` :)

Comment: @sindri_baldur yes, though since I have `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)`, that actually *adds* 51 characters (in a sense, due to the warning ;-).

Answer (score 2):

```
DF$Score_status <- 1
DF$Score_status[is.na(DF$Score)] <- 0

#   Sample_ID Score Score_status
# 1        a1   100            1
# 2        a2   200            1
# 3        a3   300            1
# 4        a4   400            1
# 5        a5    NA            0
# 6        a6    NA            0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `transform`, and convert `!is.na` to binary numbers using `+`.

```
DF <- transform(DF, Score_status=+!is.na(Score))
DF
#   Sample_ID Score Score_status
# 1        a1   100            1
# 2        a2   200            1
# 3        a3   300            1
# 4        a4   400            1
# 5        a5    NA            0
# 6        a6    NA            0
```

Comment: Wouldn't the not-so-concice `as.integer()` be better practice?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Who judges? `+` is faster.